# Including libraries in components through computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When I try to call libraries such as `lodash` or `momentjs` inside the `{{ mustache syntax }}` in Vue template files I keep getting the `'undefined property'` error, even though they are bound to the `window` object.

To go around this, I am importing the libraries into my components, and then returning the objects in computed properties, as in:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
    computed: {
        _() { return _; }
    }
}
```

Is it a good way to handle this issue? What would be the recommended approach? Are there any downsides to handling it through computed properties instead of methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes, creating a `computed` property is the way to go.

But you have some alternatives to make that simpler.

A [**Global Mixin**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) is one good alternative that requires little code:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    window() { return window; }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ window.location.host }}</p>
</div>
```

This way the `window` computed property will be available to (and thus usable in the template of) any Vue component.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the use of a global Mixin. In my particular use case it's even more appropriate, I think, than loading the libraries to computed properties.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to move all logic to compute property. This makes your code cleaner and more readable.

Think of your component as MVC, where templates are View, the component object is a controller and properties and computed properties are model. You don't put logic in the view layer, right?

So instead of

```
<template>
  <div>
   {{ _.differenceBy([{ 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], [{ 'x': 1 }], 'x') }}
  </div>
</template>

export default {
    computed: {
        _() { return _; }
    }
}
```

something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
   {{ diff1 }}
  </div>
</template>

export default {
    computed: {
        diff1: _.differenceBy([{ 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], [{ 'x': 1 }], 'x'),
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I am using both lodash and moment for formatting purposes, so it's not really the application logic (my bad, I didn't include this information in my question). But I agree with you - if it was some more complex logic it wouldn't belong to templates.